# Python: TypeError: Invalid comparison between dtype=datetime64[ns] and date

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

For a current project, I am planning to filter a JSON file by timeranges by running several loops, each time with a slightly shifted range. The code below however yields the error `TypeError: Invalid comparison between dtype=datetime64[ns] and date` for line `after_start_date = df["Date"] >= start_date`.

I have already tried to modify the formatting of the dates both within the Python code as well as the corresponding JSON file. Is there any smart tweak to align the date types/formats?

The JSON file has the following format:

```
[
{"No":"121","Stock Symbol":"A","Date":"05/11/2017","Text Main":"Sample text"}
]
```

And the corresponding code looks like this:

```
import string
import json

import pandas as pd
import datetime
from dateutil.relativedelta import *


# Loading and reading dataset
file = open("Glassdoor_A.json", "r")
data = json.load(file)
df = pd.json_normalize(data)
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])


# Create an empty dictionary
d = dict()

# Filtering by date

start_date = datetime.date.fromisoformat('2017-01-01')
end_date = datetime.date.fromisoformat('2017-01-31')

for i in df.iterrows():
    start_date += relativedelta(months=+3)
    end_date += relativedelta(months=+3)

    print(start_date)
    print(end_date)

    after_start_date = df["Date"] >= start_date
    before_end_date = df["Date"] <= end_date

    between_two_dates = after_start_date & before_end_date
    filtered_dates = df.loc[between_two_dates]

    print(filtered_dates)
```

Comment: you could just remove the 'date', i.e. `datetime.fromisoformat('...')`

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use `pd.to_datetime('2017-01-31')` instead of `datetime.date.fromisoformat('2017-01-31')`.

I hope this helps!

Comment: Small addition. The `pd.to_datetime` method is `tz-naive`. If the dataframe column is `tz-aware`, you should localize the datetime:

`pd.to_datetime('2017-01-31').tz_localize('UTC')`

Answer (score 2):

My general advice is not to use *datetime* module.
Use rather built-in *pandasonic* methods / classes like *pd.to_datetime*
and *pd.DateOffset*.

You should also close the input file as early as it is not needed, e.g.:

```
with open('Glassdoor_A.json', 'r') as file:
    data = json.load(file)
```

Other weird points in your code are that:

- you wrote a loop iterating over rows `for i in df.iterrows():`,
  but never use `i` (control variable of this loop).
- your loop works rather in a **time step** (not "row by row") mode,
  so your loop should be rather something like "while end_date <=
  last_end_date:",
- the difference between *start_date* and *end_date* is just
  **1** month (actually they are dates of start and end of some month),
  but in the loop you increase both dates by **3** months.

Below you have an example of code to look for rows in consecutive months,
up to some final date and print rows from the current month if any:

```
start_date = pd.to_datetime('2017-01-01')
end_date = pd.to_datetime('2017-03-31')
last_end_date = pd.to_datetime('2017-12-31')
mnthBeg = pd.offsets.MonthBegin(3)
mnthEnd = pd.offsets.MonthEnd(3)
while end_date <= last_end_date:
    filtered_rows = df[df.Date.between(start_date, end_date)]
    n = len(filtered_rows.index)
    print(f'Date range: {start_date.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")} - {end_date.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")},  {n} rows.')
    if n > 0:
        print(filtered_rows)
    start_date += mnthBeg
    end_date += mnthEnd
```

Comment: Thanks for the input, I am currently trying to adapt this to the `filtered_dates` output, which is basis for a further part of the code. The difference of one month was a transcription error, the "starting" `end_date` should be 31/03/2017.

Comment: So I corrected the initial setting of *end_date* and both time offsets to **3** months.

Comment: *"My general advice is not to use datetime module"* this should be put into context - ***if you primarily work with `pandas` data structures***

Comment: Of course. Your question was just about an error when dealing with *Pandas* objects, so I thought it was obvious.

Answer (score 0):

You can compare your dates using the following method

```
from datetime import datetime
df_subset = df.loc[(df['Start_Date'] > datetime.strptime('2018-12-31', '%Y-%m-%d'))]
```